# Generating admission number using id in MYSQL. I want code from CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

In my project, I have a student id no. It should auto increment. I want to auto-generate an admission number. How do I do it?

This is my controller

```
$insert_id = $this->student_model->add($data);

$data_new = array(
    'student_id' => $insert_id,
    'class_id' => $class_id,
    'section_id' => $section_id,
```

This is my model

```
public function add($data) {

    if (isset($data['id'])) {
        $this->db->where('id', $data['id']);
        $this->db->update('students', $data);
    } else {
        $this->db->insert('students', $data);

        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
}
```

Here is my view

```
                <form id="form1" action="<?php echo site_url('student/create') ?>"  id="employeeform" name="employeeform" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="box-body">

                        <div class="tshadow mb25 bozero">    

                            <h4 class="pagetitleh2"><?php echo $this->lang->line('student'); ?> <?php echo $this->lang->line('admission'); ?> </h4>


                            <div class="around10">
                                <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('msg')) { ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg') ?>
                                <?php } ?>  
                                <?php echo $this->customlib->getCSRF(); ?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="sibling_name" value="<?php echo set_value('sibling_name'); ?>" id="sibling_name_next">
                                <input type="hidden" name="sibling_id" value="<?php echo set_value('sibling_id',0); ?>" id="sibling_id">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo $this->lang->line('admission_no'); ?></label> <small class="req"> *</small> 
                                            <input autofocus="" id="admission_no" name="admission_no" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('admission_no', date($this->customlib->getSchoolDateFormat())); ?>" name="admission_no" class="form-control">
                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('admission_no'); ?></span>
                                        </div>
```

Here admission number put manually, but I want it auto-created. I don't know how to do. I'm new with CodeIgniter.

My database
[image]

My form view
[image]

Answer (score 0):

*if you want to add unique admission you must chick the `admission` or use this query*

```
$this->db->order_by('admission_no','DESC');
$this->db->get('students',1)->row()->admission_no + 1;
```

*Put the bellow code in your view in your `admission input which id of it is id="admission_no" romove the input and copy paste the code`. this get the lastest admission no and then add 1 to the admission no also you can remove this value and add manually another value. that must be unique*

```
<?php 
     $this->db->order_by('admission_no','DESC');
     $auto-add = $this->db->get('students',1)->row()->admission_no + 1;
?>
<input autofocus="" id="admission_no" name="admission_no" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo  $auto-add; ?>" class="form-control">
```

Comment: i want generating admission number automatically it taken from last admission no. database had auto increment id. i don't know how to code. please help me. and tell  where to i want put code also.please. imagine my last admission num is 2500. after i want 2501, 2502,

Comment: if i send my project can you check it?

Comment: no, I don't have enough time. show me here the problem.

Comment: add new student and then see the result.

Comment: I'm already checked. but not working, only showing 0. in database null

Comment: ok so bad. update your question with the newly edited code I want to see the code.